# Distribute list of processes to many windows machines

Tags: windows, distributed-computing

I have a list of independent tests which run a common executable with different command lines and in different working directories.

At the moment i simple run these one after the other in a batch file or script on my personal machine. However i have access to a large number of machines and so would like to be able to send some of these processes to the other machine and then collect up the output once they finish.

I could write something in python or whatever to do this, but I'm sure that someone has already done this much better than I could manage.

Any Ideas ??

cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 0):

If you have do this repeatedly over a long time, I suggest you take a look at [BOINC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Open_Infrastructure_for_Network_Computing).
Quoting from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOINC_client%E2%80%93server_technology): "BOINC is designed to be a free structure for anyone wishing to start a distributed computing project."

You would use the [BOINC API](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/BasicApi) and [you will have to set up a server](http://www.spy-hill.net/myers/help/boinc/Create_Project.html).

There are [several people who have used BOINC](https://www.google.com/search?q=using+boinc+for+my+own+projects) for their own projects: [example 1](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/dev/forum_thread.php?id=4488), [example 2](http://pirates.spy-hill.net/forum_thread.php?id=770), [example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888411/any-experience-programming-for-boinc).

Note that BOINC is especially suited for CPU-intensive processes. If your test processes are light on CPU but heavy on disk or memory, BOINC may not be suited.